# Como Agilizar el Tiempo de Busqueda de un MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

estoy realizando unos graficos estadisticos, los cuales los extraigo de una tabla que presenta 30000 registros y los mostrare en graficos(HIGHCHARTS)... resulta que cuando hago la primera consulta para completar las opciones de mi select, demora alrededor de 20 segundos en cargar

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts/js/themes/grid.js"></script>
 <script src="js/highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">

<select name="inc_sem_zon_per" id="inc_sem_zon_per" >
                <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                            <?php
                           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                           mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                           $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT region FROM registro_tecno group by region"); 
                           while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                               $regionx=$data['region'];
                               echo "<option value='".$regionx."' $selected>".$regionx."</option>"; 
                              }
                          ?>                 
            </select>
            <select name="fecha" id="fecha">
                <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
                <option value="semanas">semana</option>
                <option value="meses">mes</option>               
            </select>
            <select name="semanas" id="semanas"  hidden>
                <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
                <option value="TODOS">TODOS</option>
                            <?php
                           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                           mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                           $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT semana FROM registro_tecno group by semana"); 
                           while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                               $semanax=$data['semana'];
                               echo "<option value='".$semanax."' $selected>".$semanax."</option>"; 
                              }
                          ?>                 
            </select>   
            <select name="meses" id="meses"  hidden>
                <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
                <option value="TODOS">TODOS</option>
                            <?php
                           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                           mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                           $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT MONTH(fecha_notificacion) as meses FROM registro_tecno group by MONTH(fecha_notificacion)"); 
                           while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                               $mesx=$data['meses'];
                               echo "<option value='".$mesx."' $selected>".$mesx."</option>"; 
                              }
                          ?>                 
            </select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="anadir();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" >BUSCAR</button>
 </div>

  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  <script >
  $( function() {
    $("#fecha").change(function() {
        if($(this).val()==="meses"){
            $("#semanas").prop("hidden",true);
            $("#semanas").prop("value=null",true);
            $("#meses").prop("hidden",false);
        }else{
            $("#semanas").prop("hidden",false);
            $("#meses").prop("value=null",true);
            $("#meses").prop("hidden",true);
        }
    });
   });
  </script> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

entonces al momento de presionar el boton "buscar", mando los valores escogidos por AJAX, el cual se realiza en funciones.js

```
function anadir(){
  var parametros={
    "inc_sem_zon_per": $("#inc_sem_zon_per").val(),
    "fecha": $("#fecha").val(),
    "meses": $("#meses").val(),
    "semanas": $("#semanas").val(),
}
$.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url:"mostrar.php",
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#container").html("Procesando...");
    },
    success: function(vista){
        $("#container").html(vista);
    }
  });
 }
```

entonces envia los valores a mostrar.php , y aca ocurre mi segunda demora, ya que al momento de dar click en "buscar" se queda cargando exactamente por un minuto, y luego lo muestra en la grafica... mi codigo de mostrar.php muestra la siguiente busqueda en el mysql

```
<?php

$inc_sem_zon_per=$_POST['inc_sem_zon_per'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$meses=$_POST['meses'];
$semanas=$_POST['semanas'];
  include("conexion.php");
$estado[0]="En Curso";
$estado[1]="Pendiente";
$estado[2]="Resuelto";


  if ($fecha=="semanas") {     

          $semana_max=$con->query("SELECT MAX(semana) as sem_max FROM registro_tecno ");
          while($row_sem_max= mysqli_fetch_array($semana_max, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
            $me_max= $row_sem_max["sem_max"];
          }

          $limite_inferior=(int)$me_max-(int)$semanas;


        for ($i=0; $i <=2 ; $i++) { 
            $c=0;
          $a="";
          for ($j=$limite_inferior+1; $j <=$me_max ; $j++) { 

          $result_inc =$con->query("SELECT count(incidencia) as ver FROM registro_tecno where (estado='".$estado[$i]."' and region='".$inc_sem_zon_per."' and semana=".$j.") GROUP by semana");
         $rown3=$result_inc->num_rows;
          if ($rown3==0) {
            $a=$a."0,";
                $c++; 
           }else{
            while($row_inc= mysqli_fetch_array($result_inc, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
              {
                $inc[$c] = $row_inc["ver"];
                $a=$a.$inc[$c].",";
                $c++;                
              }
           } 

          }
          $s[$i]=$a;
          echo "estado: ".$estado[$i];
          echo "<br>ver ".$s[$i]."<br>";
        } 

  mysqli_close($con);
}elseif ($fecha=="meses") {
 $c=0;
          $acum_asig="";
          $m_max=$con->query("SELECT MAX(mes) as mes_max FROM registro_tecno ");
          while($row_mes_max= mysqli_fetch_array($m_max, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
            $me_max= $row_mes_max["mes_max"];
            echo "ver: ".$me_max;
          }

          $limite_inferior=(int)$me_max-(int)$meses;
          echo "<br>ver4: ".$limite_inferior;


        for ($i=0; $i <=2 ; $i++) { 
            $c=0;
          $a="";
          for ($j=$limite_inferior+1; $j <=$me_max ; $j++) { 

          $result_inc =$con->query("SELECT count(incidencia) as ver FROM registro_tecno where (estado='".$estado[$i]."' and region='".$inc_sem_zon_per."' and mes=".$j.") GROUP by mes");
         $rown3=$result_inc->num_rows;
          if ($rown3==0) {
            $a=$a."0,";
                $c++; 
           }else{
            while($row_inc= mysqli_fetch_array($result_inc, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
              {
                $inc[$c] = $row_inc["ver"];
                $a=$a.$inc[$c].",";
                $c++;                
              }
           } 

          }
          $s[$i]=$a;
        }  

  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                <?php for($y=$limite_inferior+1;$y<=$me_max;$y++){ echo "'MES ".$y."',";}?>
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [

        <?php for($h=0;$h<=2;$h++){?>
                       {
                        name: <?php  echo "'".$estado[$h]."',";  ?>
                        data: [
                        <?php 
                            echo $s[$h];

                        ?>
                        ]
                     },
                     <?php }?>

        ]
    });
});


</script>
```

entonces regresa el resultado, pero lo que pasa es que se demora demasiado, entonces mi pregunta seria, ¿habra alguna manera de hacer una consulta al MYSQL y que no demore demasiado?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes no agrupes en las consultas en vez de eso usa un distinct

```
"SELECT region FROM registro_tecno group by region"
```

usa

```
"SELECT distinct region FROM registro_tecno"
```

Comment: Ademas, no necesita el `GROUP BY` en las consultas del segundo bloque porque tiene `WHERE semana = '$j' GROUP BY semana`

Comment: he modificado como me han hecho notar, pero el tiempo de demora sigue siendo el mismo... :/